# Robotium and ActiveAndroid

Tags: android, robotium, activeandroid

Disclaimer: this is my first ever Android test project with Robotium.

I'm facing a catch-22 situation with ActiveAndroid and Robotium. Here's my setup:

1. I want to test an activity that expects a long array extra. This array contains DB ids of ActiveAndroid objects.
2. To get the ActiveAndroid objects ids', I need to initialize ActiveAndroid first, calling `ActiveAndroid.initialize(this.getActivity())` from my `ActivityInstrumentationTestCase2` class.
3. The call to `getActivity()` fails since I didn't pass the long array extra. I can't create the long array extra because I haven't initialized ActiveAndroid, hence the catch-22.

Is there another way I can get a context in a test class? An application-wide context perhaps?

Answer (score 0):

I found the solution:

```
ActiveAndroid.initialize(this.getInstrumentation().getTargetContext());
```

That way you can get the target's context before initializing the activity.

Comment: This does not provide an answer to the question. To critique or request clarification from an author, leave a comment below their post.

Comment: Why isn't it an answer? I'm getting a suitable context without instantiating the Activity first.